# Spacy model types and available functionality mapping

Tags: spacy

Spacy [models](https://spacy.io/usage/models) are associated with different 'types' including: vocabulary, syntax, entities and vectors. The way that entities and vectors map to features available in a document is obvious (entity recognition and word vectors) but how do vocabulary and syntax relate to features available in a document after parsing text? For example, the multi-lingual model 'xx_ent_wiki_sm' does not offer 'vocabulary' so does that mean that the is_oov of tokens will be unavailable using that model? I'm asking this because I want to provide a web service on top of Spacy that operates on different language models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"syntax" refers to the dependency parse all all related linguistic features and properties. For example, `token.dep_`, `token.head`, `doc.noun_chunks` or `doc.sents` – essentially, everything that requires the dependency parse ([see this page](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-dependency-parse) for a quick overview).

"vocabulary" means that the `Vocab` is pre-populated with a number of the most frequent words. If the model doesn't come with a vocab, all tokens will be out-of-vocabulary and return `True` for `is_oov`. Larger models typically also ship with larger vocabulary. The `sm` models should also ship with a basic vocabulary of the most frequent words – but there might be an issue with the way some of the data is currently set, which should be fixed in the next update to the models.